# How to upload json objects from a file to couchdb using a shell script?

Tags: json, bash, upload, couchdb, jq

Sample json array

```
[
{
   id : 1,
   name : Amit,
   age : 18,
   inSchool : 1;
}, 
{
   id : 2,
   name : Sunil,
   age : 21,
   inSchool : 0;
}, 
{
   id : 3,
   name : Anil,
   age : 17,
   inSchool : 1;
}
]
```

I want ->

Loop over this JSON array from file and stores these json objects in couchdb.

If there's any good way to do this. Please help me.

Comment: What kind of an operation?

Comment: Actually, i need to store those json objects in couchdb as a document

Comment: If I say "The good way to loop over a JSON array and perform an operation on each object in it is to use `map` in `jq`, e.g. `jq 'map(.age += 1)' < myfile.json` to add 1 to each age" I will have answered the question you posted, but I'm guessing you won't find it useful to solve your problem. Can you please edit your question and include enough detail so that the answer you get will be helpful to you without any follow-up questions?

Comment: @thatotherguy, i have edited my question into actual thing i want to do. please have a look.

Comment: Have you considered using CouchDB [bulk uploads](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/bulk-api.html#inserting-documents-in-bulk) to upload them all in one operation?

Comment: How to do this, can u give an example, please? Better if you can give a simple command or step by step operations to perform. I need to perform this in shell script

Comment: Suggest looking at [couchdb upload json](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=couchdb+upload+json) answers.  Jq might be able to help but uploading data to couchdb isn't something it does.

Answer (score 0):

For a real JSON file, like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Amit",
        "age": 18,
        "inSchool": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sunil",
        "age": 21,
        "inSchool": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Anil",
        "age": 17,
        "inSchool": 1
    }
]
```

you can loop over this JSON array using script based on:

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.id) \(.age) \(.inSchool) \(.name)"' fixed.json | \
while read -r    id     age     inSchool     name
do
    echo "- item[id = ${id}]: name: ${name}, age: ${age}, inSchool: ${inSchool}"

    # Add command to upload to couchdb

done
```

output:

```
➜ bash script.sh
 - item[id = 1]: name: Amit, age: 18, inSchool: 1
 - item[id = 2]: name: Sunil, age: 21, inSchool: 0
 - item[id = 3]: name: Anil, age: 17, inSchool: 1
```